# EF Core 3 x.where extension method return IEnumerable not IQueryable

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

The EF Core 3 `Where` extension method returns `IEnumerable<>`, which returns all the rows from the database. Instead, I want `IQueryable<>` because I want to build the query based in conditions and I don't want to hit the database before I complete building the query.

```
IQueryable<TEntity> query = _dbset.Where(predicate)
if(condition)
query = query.where(predicate)
```

Comment: What is the **type** of `predicate`? If it is a `Func<>`  (and not `Expression<Func<>>`), then `Where` will return `IEnumerable<>` in all LINQ versions (has nothing to do with EF Core).

Comment: @IvanStoev thank you i converted the predicate to Expression<Func<>> and its working .